# Ошибки socket.io

Tags: node.js, сокет

Запустил socket.io на сервере, получаю ошбики в консоле, подскажите где копать)
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
var app = require('express')();
var http = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(http);

app.get('/', function(req, res){
  res.sendFile('index.html');
});

io.on('connection', function(socket){
  console.log('a user connected');
  socket.on('disconnect', function(){
    console.log('user disconnected');
  });
});

io.on('connection', function(socket){
  socket.on('chat message', function(msg){
    io.emit('chat message', msg);
  });
});

http.listen(3000, function(){
  console.log('listening on *:3000');
});
```

привел код скрипта) может там что-то нето....

Comment: на стороне сервера смотреть что пишется в логи и исправлять ошибки

Comment: Прикол в том что тоже самое на локалке работает нормально..

Comment: ну так вы логи смотрите, я же не вижу ваш код, не знаю что именно у вас на локалке работает

Comment: Логи в студию, пожалуйста

Comment: Стесняюсь спросить, а где логи брать?)

Comment: @pwnz22 Это вы у саппорта https://www.phusionpassenger.com/ спросите